# Laravel - Get instance of file from string path

Tags: php, windows, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

My laravel application successfully uploads and stores my files where I want them to.  However, I don't want to store the public url of the file in the database, and instead get them on the fly (they're stored in my `public` directory) and show a list of links to the uploads.

How can I retrieve File objects from just the strings returned by `File::files(public_path() . "/files/uploads");` so I can get the name, size, modified date, etc?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (File::allFiles($directory) as $file)
{
    /* $file should be a Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo object */
    $file->getSize();
    $file->getFilename();
    $file->getType();
}
```

[Documentation for the SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php). (Thanks @Bogdan!)

Comment: Unfortunately File::get() returns the physical contents of the file, not a file object from the file path.

Comment: Ah. It's been a few months since I played with Laravel's File class.

Comment: File::allFiles() returns an array of strings of the absolute path of the file, not an SplFileInfo instance.

Comment: @JoshAllen actually `File::files` returns an array of strings, @nivixzixer correcty pointed out that `File::allFiles` returns an array of [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) instances.

Comment: I completely overlooked that! This is answer I was looking for! Laravel's documentation really needs to point out that files returns an array while allFiles returns a SplFileInfo instance. Thank you both so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
foreach (File::files(public_path() . '/fonts') as $path)
{
    File::size($path);         // file size
    File::name($path);         // file name (no extension)
    File::extension($path);    // file extension
    File::mimeType($path);     // file mime type
    File::lastModified($path); // file last modified timestamp
    // and so on...
}
```

You can see all methods available in the [`Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html) class API.

Comment: Is there a way in Laravel to return a File instance object and do something like `$file->size()`? I think that is what the OP is asking..

Comment: This works great, though there's gotta be a better way than manually calling those methods and passing the string each time.  Is there an easier way to initialize a file object that stores that information (rather than building the array/object manually)?

Comment: @nivixzixer's answer actually uses object instances instead of the Laravel's static facades, so that's a better solution to your issue.