# Validate a file from Storage Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-filesystem

### Scenario

I am working on a project where `csv` files are uploaded and processed. Following is a use case:

- Task 1: User A can upload `data.csv` using interface or ftp
- Task 2: User B selects a certain `csv` file from UI and process it

### Problem

File upload is an easier task. I have a form and using `storeAs` method to store the data.

```
$thisFltFile->storeAs($directory,$file);
```

Now I have another form to achieve `Task 2` where `User B` selects the file names in the `$directory` listed using:

```
$filelist = Storage::allFiles($directory);
```

When the user submits the form, it triggers a method in `controller` where I want to validate the file before processing it from the file path since the files can be uploaded from `ftp` too. For example:

```
$rules = array('file' => 'required|file|mimetypes:text/plain|mimes:txt,dat,csv',);
$this->validate($file,$rules);
```

### Explored

Unfortunately, there isn't a `File` facade with Laravel 5.3 which can retrieve the file instance from the path like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463117/laravel-get-instance-of-file-from-string-path). I have tried `Storage::get($path)` but it seems to retrieve the file contents.

Additionally following have been explored:

1. [Laravel retrieve physical file instance onto input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253974/laravel-retrieve-physical-file-instance-onto-input-file)
2. [Laravel - file path to UploadedFile instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827765/laravel-file-path-to-uploadedfile-instance)

### Environment

Following are specifications for my development environment:

1. Host os: Ubuntu 14.04
2. Virtual Environment: Vagrant
3. Server platform: Centos 7.2
4. Laravel version: Laravel 5.3

Comment: Can you paste code what kind of validation you want to do on the file?

Comment: Updated an example

Comment: Try this to instantiate a file already stored in storage new UploadedFile(Storage::path($file->path), $file->clientname,  null, null, true);